# Iterate through array and bind events

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, bind, unbind

I've checked through the forum and cant seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have an array of id's and I'm iterating through them with a for loop adding mouse events for enter and leave. 
However the events all bind to the final ID, which is probably a for each issue.

I've put it up on a fiddle below, any help would be appreciated - my brain is a bit frazzled today.

http://jsfiddle.net/shanemccster/e48vu/4/

```
cards = new Array('#box0','#box1','#box2');
function bindCardEvents(){
    for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++){
        var targetID = '#'+$(cards[i]).attr('id');
        $(targetID)
            .mouseenter(function() {
                TweenMax.to(targetID,0.3, {opacity:0.5} )
            }).mouseleave(function() {
                TweenMax.to(targetID,0.3, {opacity:1}) 
            }); 
    }
}
bindCardEvents();
```

Thanks

Comment: I recommend to add some class selector for all this(like a `.card`), or use `[id^=box]` selector

Comment: Your fault is incorrect events understanding(or js closures) When events triggered `targetID` already overriden by next loop iterations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/LQEWU/)***

You can just join the ids together with `,` which by convention adds the selectors to a set in jQuery. After doing that, you can assign the event to the set returned by those selectors. Each event will have access to the current element `this`. `TweenMax.to` expects a selector or an element, so you can pass `this` into the function without manually constructing an id selector.

```
var cards = new Array('#box0','#box1','#box2');
var cardSelector = cards.join(",");
function bindCardEvents(){
  $(cardSelector).mouseenter(function() {
    TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:0.5} )
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:1}) 
  });
}
bindCardEvents();
```

For brevity this will also work

```
$(cards.join(",")).mouseenter(function() {
    TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:0.5} )
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:1}) 
});
```

Comment: @ShaneMcCarthy - It is definitely less efficient to check if every element on the page has an id which starts with box. If you want to save time, just use `$(cards.join(',')).mouseenter` ... which trades 3 characters for a far higher efficient selection.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think of that. Good point, looks like I'll be sticking with your example. Thanks for your help Travis.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to iterate. You can use like

```
   $("[id^=box]")
        .mouseenter(function() {
            TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:0.5} )
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            TweenMax.to(this,0.3, {opacity:1}) 
        });
```

It will bind the events to all the elements whose id starts with `box`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e48vu/7/)

Comment: FYI: you now have an undefined `targetID`

Comment: @vp_arth, I know, I was letting the author know so he can update his answer.

Comment: Such a simple thing, I love when I learn something new. Thank you!